# vue: splice does not work on the current element

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, splice

I have an array of objects like this:

```
  daySelected: [
    {
      selectDay: day,
      time: [
        {
          defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
          defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      selectDay: day,
      time: [
        {
          defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
          defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
        }
      ]
    },
     //etc....
  ];
```

the array is formed with this function which pushes an object on click:

```
 const object = {
    selectDay: day,
    time: [
      {
        defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
        defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
      },
    ], 
  };
 this.daySelected.push (object);
```

so far it works... the problem arises when I want to delete the current pushed element:

```
 this.daySelected.splice(this.daySelected.indexOf(object), 1);
```

if I click on the element at the end of the array to delete it it works, but if I click on a middle element or at the beginning of the array, it deletes the next one...

Comment: How are you indicating the middle element?? for the object you know this is the last element. Or you know `object` is a name.

Comment: You can try with `Vue.delete()` ref: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist I tried with: 
`this.$delete(this.daySelected, this.daySelected.indexOf(object));`
but it did not work

Comment: Why you are trying to get `indexOf(object)` all time?
You are pushing the `object` in the last. Then how will you expect middle element will delete?

Comment: so how can i use delete?

Comment: You can also use `splice()` but you can't pass indexOf `object` all the time.

Comment: Use this: `this.daySelected.splice(this.daySelected.indexOf(this), 1);`

Comment: so it doesn't work, it's the same thing ... if I want to use Vue.delete () how could I write it?

Comment: Give your full code with onclick event

Comment: unfortunately I don't have onclick, as I'm using this library =>
https://github.com/Digital-Threads/vue-functional-calendar 
which allows me to use: @dayClicked="dayClicked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than indicate the index by `this.daySelected.indexOf(object)`, try to indicate directly from the `v-for`.
You maybe iterate the `daySelected` array using `v-for` as follows:

```
<div v-for="(obj, index) in daySelected">
...
// use `index` to pass as a parameter of the `splice` method.
... deleteObj(index) ...
...
</div>
```

```
<script>
...
  methods: {
    deleteObj(index) {
       this.daySelected.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not using v-for because i get that data from a library ... i tried with:

     `this.daySelected.map(function (obj, index) {
          return Object.assign(daySelectedObj, { id: index });
        });`

but it doesn't work ... on the first try, delete the right one, then delete the next one

Comment: can you attach your whole codebase with how daySelected.map is used and also the delete method?

Comment: Im using this library => https://github.com/Digital-Threads/vue-functional-calendar

Comment: in your updated code, you have used `v-for="day in daySelected"`, update it to `v-for="(day, index) in daySelected"`, and then `day.selectDay.slice(index, 6)`

Comment: where should I enter day.selectDay.slice (index, 6)?

Comment: in your click event. you may need to add click method

Comment: but my click comes from that library 
@dayClicked="dayClicked"
can't add it